# program group entry

Tags: 22.04, xilinx

I am trying to uninstall Xilinx Vivado on my Ubuntu system. However, before doing so. the folders `/opt/Xilinx` and `/root/.Xilinx` were removed manually.
So, I tried to reinstall Vivado to be able to safefly uninstall it afterwards. But the installation process fails with the following error:

```
ERROR - Program group entry, Xilinx Design Tools, already exists for 2022.2. Specify a different program group entry.
```

I am not quite sure what the "Program group entry" is. How do I fix this?

Thanks!